# Convert a python 'type' object to a string

Tags: python, reflection

I'm wondering how to convert a python 'type' object into a string using python's reflective capabilities.

For example, I'd like to print the type of an object

```
print("My type is " + type(some_object))  # (which obviously doesn't work like this)
```

Comment: What do you consider the "type" of an object to be? And what doesn't work about what you posted?

Comment: Apologies, print type(someObject) does actually work :)

Answer (score 348, accepted):

```
print(type(some_object).__name__)
```

If that doesn't suit you, use this:

```
print(some_instance.__class__.__name__)
```

Example:

```
class A:
    pass
print(type(A()))
# prints <type 'instance'>
print(A().__class__.__name__)
# prints A
```

Also, it seems there are differences with `type()` when using new-style classes vs old-style (that is, inheritance from `object`). For a new-style class, `type(someObject).__name__` returns the name, and for old-style classes it returns `instance`.

Comment: Doing `print(type(someObject))` will print the full name (ie. including the package)

Comment: Strangely `__name__` does not appear in the `dir(float)` etc.

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> class A(object): pass

>>> e = A()
>>> e
<__main__.A object at 0xb6d464ec>
>>> print type(e)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> print type(e).__name__
A
>>>
```

What do you mean by "convert into a string?" You can define your own `__repr__` and `__str__` methods:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'hei, i am A or B or whatever'

>>> e = A()
>>> e
hei, i am A or B or whatever
>>> str(e)
hei, i am A or B or whatever
```

or i dont know..please add explainations ;)

Comment: Btw. I think your original answer had str(type(someObject)) which was also helpful

Answer (score 6):

```
print("My type is %s" % type(someObject)) # the type in python
```

or...

```
print("My type is %s" % type(someObject).__name__) # the object's type (the class you defined)
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to use `str()` and a custom **str** method. This also works for repr.

```
class TypeProxy:
    def __init__(self, _type):
        self._type = _type

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._type(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._type.__name__

    def __repr__(self):
        return "TypeProxy(%s)" % (repr(self._type),)

>>> str(TypeProxy(str))
'str'
>>> str(TypeProxy(type("")))
'str'
```

Answer (score 3):

By using the str() function you can do this.

```
 typeOfOneAsString=str(type(1))  # changes the type to a string type
```