# Sorting mixed variable types allowed in python 2 but not in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am upgrading my script from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6 but the issue is sorting doesn't allow different types. Previously it would put strings at one end and numbers (int, float, etc) at the other.

Is there a workout in Python 3 for it to behave like it did in Python 2?

Python 2.7.13:

```
>>> x = [1, 'a']
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
[1, 'a']
```

Python 3.7.3:

```
>>> x = [1, 'a']
>>> x.sort()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

The above is a skeleton example.

My real code in Python 2 is something like this:

```
>>> results =  ['delete', 'delete', ['0285', 13.98], ['2746', 13.98], 'delete']
>>> results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> results
[['0285', 13.98], ['2746', 13.98], 'delete', 'delete', 'delete']
```

A key is defined, which is the 2nd element of a list, as `results` represents a list of lists.

Comment: @aws_apprentice whatever it does in python 2. do you want me to run it in python 2?

Comment: @aws_apprentice done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting lists in python 2 lead to datatypes being sort together implicitly by some random hardcoded ordering which datatype is "less" then what other datatype. This implicit sorting vanished with python 3 - instead you need to sort explicitly by specifying the `key`:

```
# [].sort(key=...) and sorted([], key=...) both work
k = sorted( [1, "a",2,"b"], key=lambda x:type(x).__name__)

print(k)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```

---

Edit for lists of lists:

```
k = sorted( ['delete', 'delete', ['0285', 13.98], ['2746', 13.98], 'delete'],
            key=lambda x:type(x[1]).__name__)
# you could also use  key=lambda x:type(x).__name__ - it wouldthen use list/str as key
# instead of int/str for type(x[1]).__name__ 
print(k) #
```

Output:

```
[['0285', 13.98], ['2746', 13.98], 'delete', 'delete', 'delete']
```

---

Doku:

- [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
- [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Related:

- [Convert a python 'type' object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008828/convert-a-python-type-object-to-a-string)

Comment: Which if I was sorting a list of lists and wanted to sort the 2nd element of each list?

Comment: I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type'` (Python 3.6)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  fixed

Comment: @User- you should have provided your real data in the beginning ;o) - edited. Its kindiof the same, just take care you do not have things in it that are _not_ indexable and those that are have an index 1...

Comment: I'm curious, can we use `.sort()` or does it have to be changed to `sorted()` in Python 3?

Comment: Wouldn't you also sort on the value? `sorted( [2, "b",1,"a"], key=lambda x:(type(x).__name__, x))` returns `[1, 2, 'a', 'b']` as expected, and works well as no values of different types have to be compared.

Comment: I know, I should have, but I didn't expect it to use the key parameter, which was in use.

Comment: @User  `sort()` and `sorted()` both work with the key paramter - `sort()` sorts inplace - `sorted()` returns a new list, use either one

Comment: Issue, this also doesn't sort the numbers, does it? Only groups the strings and numbers?

Comment: @User if you want mutliple sort criteria, use a tuple `lambda x:(type(x).__name__, x[1])` to sort. In case of identical `__name__` the other parameter will rule the sorting - be creative. Maybe you should sit down and think what you fully want to happen, this is the third "change" of your question... the above tuple will sort strings based on the 2nd character in it and your inner lists based on the float. You probably should just write a function instead of the lamdba if you need more conditions met and use the function as key ... makes it cleaner