# General way to convert python type to descriptive string?

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm using pydantic to generate these sweet json objects which describe the attributes:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    argument_1: int = Field(..., description="desc.")

print(MyModel.model_json_schema())

# Outputs:
{'properties': {'argument_1': {'description': 'desc.', 'title': 'Argument 1', 'type': 'integer'}}, 'required': ['argument_1'], 'title': 'MyModel', 'type': 'object'}
```

It clearly states the types each property. (`'type': 'integer'`)

But now I also want to get the return type of a function in the same form.
I've tried a few things and the closest I get is the literal return type.

```py
from typing import get_type_hints


def get_return_type(obj):
    type_hints = get_type_hints(obj)
    return type_hints.get("return", "Unknown")

def my_func() -> int:
    return 10

print(get_return_type(my_func))
print(my_func.__annotations__.get("return"))
print(my_func.__annotations__.get("return").__name__)

# Outputs:
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
int
```

I wish to get the return value the same way that Pydantic gives me the type of a schema's attributes, like: "integer", "number", "string", "array" etc...

Looking at the Pydantic docs didn't make me much wiser either

- https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_json_schema
- https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.5/concepts/json_schema/#customizing-the-json-schema-generation-process

or maybe im blind :(. Though while looking though the code of [GenerateJsonSchema](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/fbed01401c6e36faff495be6323ceaf3e67b9314/pydantic/json_schema.py#L226) I did notice that it can convert types to a descriptive string, but I have no clue how to use it for my case.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008828/convert-a-python-type-object-to-a-string) comes close, but isn't quite it.

Is there a general way to achieve this? Or maybe a way to use Pydantic for this?
Or will I have to write my own custom mapping?

Comment: If you use type() you will get the string. Then with a simple dictionary you can convert it to your specific format?

Comment: @kithuto So you're suggestion I indeed write my own mapping? Is very easy to do, but I was wondering if there we're other solutions available. But thanks!

Comment: You will only need to map int to integer. type(2.5).__name__ is float and if you have a clas Object and an ithem a = Object() the resulting string will be Object: a.__class__.__name__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Pydantic doesn't offer a native way to do this, but there is a way you could go via pydantic to save writing your own mapper, using create_model:

```py
from inspect import signature
from typing import Any, Callable

from pydantic import create_model

def return_annotation_extract(f: Callable[..., Any]) -> str:
    t = signature(f).return_annotation
    p_model = create_model('dummy', dummy_field=(t,...))
    return p_model.model_json_schema()['properties']['dummy_field']['type']

def my_func() -> int:
    return 10

print(return_annotation_extract(my_func))
```

Here I use signature to extract the return annotation but the ways you suggested would also work - the signature library is just helpful for extracting all info about a function, including the function parameters. Hope this is useful!